# I'm getting Failed with exit code 1 error in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

This is my first ever attempt at a Objective-c cocoa program, so I have no clue why it is giving me that error. I really don't understand the Build Result page either.

myClass.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface myClass : NSObject {
    int a;
    int b;
}

-(void) setvara:(int)x;
-(void) setvarb:(int)y;
-(int) add;

@end
```

myClass.m

```
#import "myClass.h"


@implementation myClass

-(void)setvara:(int)x{
    a=x;    
}

-(void)setvarb:(int)y{
    b=y;    
}

-(int)add{
    return a+b; 
}
@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import "myClass.m"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    myClass* class = [[myClass alloc]init];

    [class setvara:5];
    [class setvarb:6];

    printf("The sum: %d", [class add]);

    [class release];

}
```

Comment: Try importing `<Foundation/NSObject.h>` and forget the cocoa.h

Comment: when you get a failed compilation with exit code 1, usually you can go to the build results and then click on the little button with the few horizontal lines. this will give you some compiler output that may be helpful to trackdown your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Still is throwing me the error.

Comment: Says duplicate symbol... I was reading something about Targets... do I have to set something up when compiling projects? I just want to use the console for printfs

Comment: thyrgle: One should generally not import specific classes' headers directly. The proper way is to import the framework's umbrella header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main.m, you want to import myClass.h, not myClass.m

The header file has the declarations you need. If you import the implementation, you are implementing those methods twice, hence the duplicate symbols.

Another tip as you learn, when you say [[myClass alloc] init], what you get back is a pointer to an object, not a class. So you should call it an object just so that concept is reinforced for you. Getting the difference straight now will help you greatly as you get deeper into this.

(there are a couple of naming convention issues here also, btw)

Comment: Ok so it is a class but it creates an object?

Comment: yes, you send an 'alloc' message to a class, and what you get back is a pointer to an object. Then you send an 'init' message to that object, and you get back a pointer to an object that is now initialized and ready to use.

Comment: Hey i tried your code and i found that in the main.m file you are importing the myclass.m file it should be myclass.h apart from this issue your code just works fine man.